# ldap_bind: Invalid Credentials (49) How can I solve it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap

When I try to use the command `ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=jonaserver,dc=com -W -f ou.ldif` it asks me for a password which I'm supposed to put right. But it always says `invalid credentials ( 49)`

What can I do?

The password should work but no, it doesn't work for me, I get the error Invalid Credentials (49)

Comment: Some ideas: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Ldap-Authentication-issue-ldap-bind-Invalid-credentials-49/m-p/223168

Comment: Can you type the password using the same keyboard to make sure that is working?